# Need help in selecting html5 canvas framework

Tags: html, canvas

I need some suggestions in choosing a html5 canvas framework for my project
The project aims at developing a visualization application based on some data and using generative art.

Can someone provide some pointers to a mature framework. Some of the essential requirements I am looking for are as follows

1. Scenegraph based model with multiple layers.
2. Standard ZUI (Zoom able user interface ) features like , pan, zoom, move ,
   rotate, scale , translate , position etc.
3. Animation , both frame based and object based (should be able to pick a object in the    scenegraph and animate from one point to another like the PPT animation paths).
4. Apart from mouse , keyboard and touch , should support programmatic events based on custom events/timers etc  (required for generative art based rendering)
5. Should support desktop browsers as well as phones.

I have come across many great frameworks like

- Paper.js
- Kinetic.js
- Fabric.js
- Easel.js

All of them support the first and the second requirement ( at least partially )
but not sure about the others.

Please suggest a mature framework.

Comment: See 2d canvas libraries comparison table — https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

Answer (score 2):

After some more research and posting this question on the mailing lists of the above mentioned  frameworks, I have finally decided on Paper.js

Paper.js looks very impressive and the code style looks neat compared to others.

Although I was also impressed by Kinetic.js but for now it is under wraps.

Easel.js is also very promising but since it is still in alpha will keep tracking it .